# Why "Missing return statement" is not handled in languages?

Tags: gcc, dart

Today I was getting introduced to Dart myself. At a point while playing with it, something was going wrong. Later I found that it was nothing but I forgot to put `return` statement in a function so null was set to the variable that was supposed to get value from that function.

At that point I was thinking, in Java it would be caught as error in the very first place. Why C/C++ or the new Dart don't add this feature? Does this feature slows the code down at a large scale? Or there are any other technical reasons behind this?

Comment: What? Every modern C/C++ compiler will trigger (at least) a warning if you forget to return from a function. e.g. `gcc -Wall -fsyntax-only -x c++ - <<< 'int f() {}'` => `<stdin>:1:10: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`

Answer (score 1):

Every method returns a value, and if there is no return it is `null`.

However it looks like this some enhancements could be done in the future. See [issue 73 : Missing return statement does not trigger warning or error](http://dartbug.com/73) and [issue 13373 : Can get the editor to warn when there is no explicit return for a function returning a type](http://dartbug.com/13373).

Comment: Yah, I agree with that of course. And from the first link, looks like they(Dart) have taken it into account.
But my point is actually, while Java has this feature why other languages don't have it? Good to see that Dart will have this feature soon.

Comment: Java is a compiled statically typed language. It is not possible for the compiler to generate code which forgets to return a value. Dart is dynamically typed language, and has a source code based VM. So you can run your code without even type checking it. Dart's static type analyzer is optimistic about many things that would be errors in Java. I personally would like to see it be more strict about this specific problem too. Star that bug ;)